# Listen for New Shells

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt

The preferences of our application are shared (i.e. all users in an office have the same one). For that to work we have implemented a custom `IPreferenceStore` that saves and (re-)loads the data to / from a database.

Now of course we can't have the `IPreferenceStore` reloading while the preference window is open - at the very least we should bring some kind of message in that case or something. So I need to have a way to listen to the `PreferenceDialog` opening.

Since we're implementing an Eclipse application, it might suffice to listen for `Shells` opening and checking their title, if it's not possible to react to the preference dialog directly.

What I tried:

```java
// this only reacts to the main window changing
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().addWindowListener(new IWindowListener() { ... });

// shells (and composites in general) are missing listeners for
// adding child controls
Shell currentShell = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getShell();
currentShell.addListener(SWT.???, e-> System.out.println(e));

// what listeners do display even have?
Display.getDefault().addListener(SWT.???, e-> System.out.println(e));
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Display.addFilter` for `SWT.Activate` does give an event as a shell is activated (and a lot of other things as well). For some reason `addListener` does not work in my test.

```java
Display.getDefault().addFilter(SWT.Activate, listener);
```

The `widget` field of the `Event` contains the control being activated.

Comment: You can also use `addFilter( SWT.Show, listener )` which will notify the listener when new widgets are shown.